# Copy vmware virtual disk contents from one to antoher?

Tags: vmware, virtual-disk

Is there a way to copy contents from one virtual disk to another? I need a way to lower size of the virtual disk, I was thinking of creating new one and copying contents from the old to new one. Also is it possible to resize virtual disk with tools like gparted so that that size is one that vmware displays?

Thanks,
Mika

Comment: VMWare offers a way to change the UID on a VMWare Virtual Machine through a command line utility.  If thats not what you wnat please explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I changed my question, see if that helps

Comment: Just change the size of the existing virtual machine.  You change the size through a vmtool console command tool then update the partition information within Windows.